# Using check boxes to select Items

Tags: silverlight, mvvm

I am building a silverlight app. My requirement is to have Users select a number of skills that apply to them, from a larger list of skills.

Tables: Candidate => CandidateSkills; SkillsCategories => Skills. I think the schema is self explanatory. The front end will show all skills (grouped into different categories), and when the candidate logs in, only his selected skills will show in the check boxes. Fairly simple.

My question: Do I bring all the Skill entities to the front end and then get the CandidateSkill entities, loop through them and set the checkboxes accordingly or is their a easier/better way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend building a class to use as a ViewModel. The class should contain at least a property to indicate whether the item is selected, the text to present, and either the model entity itself or its key.

You can create the set of view model objects by left-joining the set of all skills to the individual candidate's skills, and setting `IsSelected` to the result of a non-null test on the candidate skill.

You can then bind directly to the ViewModel.

I had a similar situation (Users to Permissions instead of Candidates to Skills) once, and I used [this resource](http://blog.benday.com/archive/2010/08/02/23283.aspx) as a starting point. I hope it helps.

In my case, I had a "Save" button which, upon click, would run some code-behind code to iterate through the selected items and submit them to my Web service. Without knowing the details of your data and service implementation, I'll not clutter up the post with the nitty-gritty details.

Best of luck!

**Comments for Discussion**

Here is a pseudo-LINQ procedure creating view models by issuing two database calls:

```
var userskills = database.CandidateSkills
                       .Where(cs => cs.UserId == someUserId)
                       .Select(cs => cs.SkillId)
                       .ToList();
var skills = from s in database.Skills
             select new CandidateSkillViewModel()
             {
                 Text = s.SkillName,
                 IsSelected = userskills.Contains(s.SkillId),
                 Value = s.SkillId
             };
mylist.ItemsSource = skills;
```

This would give you a bindable data source. Ultimately, using this pattern, you'll have to translate selections/deselections into inserts/deletes by hand. For me, I do this in the handler for the button click. I retrieve a fresh set of candidate skills, iterate through the items of the list, and insert/delete instances of CandidateSkill as needed.

I realize that depending on a button click to resolve my viewmodel state into database operations might not be considered by purists to be complete MVVM, but it worked for me.

I hope this helps a little more.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I should have mentioned I am using MVVM. My only concern was that if I did a join between CandidateSkills and Skills, I would lose change tracking. Do you know if this is the case?

Comment: Probably, though you might work around it (part of the way) by implementing INotifyPropertyChanged on your view model.

Comment: OK - so I get the collection of Candidate SKills (using RIA services) from the service layer. In the client code, I do a left outer join using LINQ and create a new collection with the Skills and Skill Categories joined. Do these (lookup) entities need an [Include] statement in the service layer as well?

Comment: Well that didnt work for me. The problem might be that I already eager load Candidate and CandidateSkills and return them in the GetCandidates call. Once there, I am struggling to connect the Skills table to the entity because my LINQ skills arent good enough!

Comment: Hi, @greg:  I added some pseudocode adapted from my solution. I hope it helps.

Comment: I am now really stumped. I have created all the collections and tested them. All populated correctly. I then used a LINQ query to pull them together but 0 records are returned???                    var candidatequery = (from cs in CandidateSkills
                                 join c in Candidates on cs.CandidateID equals c.IDCandidate
                                 join s in Skills on cs.SkillID equals s.IDSkill
                                 select new {cs.SkillID, cs.IsSelected, s.SkillDesc}).ToList();

Comment: Hi @greg: It is hard for me to be certain with the information I have; but, you may be running into problems because the join you describe is an *inner* join. Left joins are pretty sloppy in LINQ, though you can find some examples online if you determine that is what you need.

Comment: The problem must be that I am trying to join a "many side" of a relationship to another "many side" (although the data has been extracted into collections). I tried setting a one to one in the EF designer but it didnt like that. Got a gut feel its to do with keys..